# Is it possible to expire each value in redis?

Tags: redis

I would like to use redis to article(post)-read processing.
I want to store idex of each article read by each user in redis.

So key is userId  and value(may be list) is article index list.
I want to set expire time for each index value.

Is it possible? and i want to know redis commands.

--additional information

I want to key - value(list) , and expire each value in list.
If expire a key, i dont want all values to be lost. i want to delete specific one key.

the data show under,
songkeyy - [1,2,3,4,5]
expire 1 : 100ms , 2:200ms ,3:30ms... like this.

t would be nice if you could recommend the appropriate redis command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does redis expire keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36172745/how-does-redis-expire-keys)

Comment: Answer: you may set an optional expiry for each key-value pair at the same you enter it into the Redis map.  See the duplicate link for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!
I want to key - value(list) , and expire each value in list.
If expire a key, i dont want all values to be lost. i want to delete specific one key. 
``
t would be nice if you could recommend the appropriate redis command.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is surely possible

```
redis> SET mykey "Hello"
"OK"
redis> EXPIRE mykey 10
(integer) 1
redis> TTL mykey
(integer) 10
redis>
```

You can set TTLs(Time to live) on key which will expire after the given time.

Comment: Can't find an exact duplicate, but surely this question has been asked and answered before on this site.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I did search , but for the purpose of doc , i have added the answer

Answer (score 0):

The design and implementation of redis list doesn't support this operation. But there's another way to implement it.

write:

```
zadd user_id article_id expired_time
```

read:

```
zrange user_id 0 -1 WITHSCORES
```

When read req coming, fetch all article_id this user have read, and remove all expired item:

```
for i in res:
  if i.score < time.now()
    zrem user_id i.article_id
```