# Multiple concurrent dynamic locks and timeouts if failure to acquire locks

Tags: multithreading, go, locking, concurrenthashmap

I have a use case where I need to lock on arguments of a function.

The function itself can be accessed concurrently

Function signature is something like

```
func (m objectType) operate(key string) (bool) {
    // get lock on "key" (return false if unable to get lock in X ms - eg: 100 ms)
    // operate
    // release lock on "key"
    return true;
}
```

The data space which can be locked is in the range of millions (~10 million)

Concurrent access to operate() is in the range of thousands (1 - 5k)

Expected contention is low though possible in case of hotspots in key (hence the lock)

What is the right way to implement this ? Few options I explored using a concurrent hash map

1. sync.Map - this is suited for cases with append only entries and high read ratio compared to writes. Hence not applicable here
2. sharded hashmap where each shard is locked by RWMutex - https://github.com/orcaman/concurrent-map - While this would work, concurrency is limited by no of shards rather than actual contention between keys. Also doesn't enable the timeout scenarios when lot of contention happens for a subset of keys

Though timeout is a P1 requirement, the P0 requirement would be to increase throughput here by granular locking if possible.

Is there a good way to achieve this ?

Comment: I dont feel like to do an answer with it, though i dont feel like to throw it by the window either, https://play.golang.org/p/v_-TYbjPXoZ Then I have some commands like `go run . -kind chan -commit | gnuplot -p -e 'set terminal qt title "-chan -commit"; set style d hist; set style fill solid; plot "-" u 2:xtic(1) linecolor "black"   title "Counts by duration"'` to produce plots. It is less a comparison rather than a playgrond to experiment!

Answer (score 2):

I would do it by using a map of buffered channels:

- to acquire a "mutex", try to fill a buffered channel with a value
- work
- when done, empty the buffered channel so that another goroutine can use it

Example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type MutexMap struct {
    mut     sync.RWMutex        // handle concurrent access of chanMap
    chanMap map[int](chan bool) // dynamic mutexes map
}

func NewMutextMap() *MutexMap {
    var mut sync.RWMutex
    return &MutexMap{
        mut:     mut,
        chanMap: make(map[int](chan bool)),
    }
}

// Acquire a lock, with timeout
func (mm *MutexMap) Lock(id int, timeout time.Duration) error {
    // get global lock to read from map and get a channel
    mm.mut.Lock()
    if _, ok := mm.chanMap[id]; !ok {
        mm.chanMap[id] = make(chan bool, 1)
    }
    ch := mm.chanMap[id]
    mm.mut.Unlock()

    // try to write to buffered channel, with timeout
    select {
    case ch <- true:
        return nil
    case <-time.After(timeout):
        return fmt.Errorf("working on %v just timed out", id)
    }
}

// release lock
func (mm *MutexMap) Release(id int) {
    mm.mut.Lock()
    ch := mm.chanMap[id]
    mm.mut.Unlock()
    <-ch
}

func work(id int, mm *MutexMap) {
    // acquire lock with timeout
    if err := mm.Lock(id, 100*time.Millisecond); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("ERROR: %s\n", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("working on task %v\n", id)
    // do some work...
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Printf("done working on %v\n", id)

    // release lock
    mm.Release(id)
}

func main() {
    mm := NewMutextMap()
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 50; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        id := i % 10
        go func(id int, mm *MutexMap, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
            work(id, mm)
            defer wg.Done()
        }(id, mm, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

EDIT: different version, where we also handle the concurrent access to the chanMap itself

Comment: this works fine but the map can potentially grow infinetly as there is no clear way to unset the key when no one is locking it. is there a way where we can check if no one is requesting for the key, we clear the key from the map and save space

Comment: Sure, when creating a map, simply launch a goroutine that will wait for some time, then lock the map and delete the chan. If the chan is unused, it will be cleared, and if still in use it will be recreated again.
Or you could implement some kind of LU-caching mechanism. At this point I'll let you do it though :)

Comment: @DanMatlin Also, you can set a timestamp for each map key and suddenly delete keys with timestamps longer than x minutes. I suggest to read about Redis expiration mechanism: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59476667/8712494